# Can't submit app to Mac App store: "Task was not created."

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile, mac-app-store

I recreated the provisioning profiles, added the --deep flag, and now I get this:

[image]

Tried waiting a few hours, and quitting Xcode and restarting, still no go. Xcode 5.0.2. Can't figure out where to go from here.

I get the same error if I try to just Validate the app, also.

Comment: This is still baffling me. I can build the app and install it on other computers, but I keep getting this message. Any ideas for where to start looking would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it. At the final step in submitting the app, it asks you what provisioning file to sign it with. I was selecting the file that I had made on the Mac dev center, which was a release profile that I had built specifically for this app. But that was not right. (!)

What I had to do was just select my name, as the developer, which was actually already pre-selected in the field. Once I did that, it was accepted just fine. I guess I was trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be.